# Subscribe using Sendy API - AJAX POST, Status: Cancelled

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, post, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to use the Sendy API, using an AJAX POST to subscribe:

```
var testList = "hashedstring";
                var email = $j('#email').val();
                var name = $j('#name').val();
                var sendyUrl = "http://newsletters.newstimesarehere.com/subscribe";
                var dataObject = {name: name,email: email,list: testList};

            $j.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: sendyUrl,
                data: dataObject,
                success: function () {
                    alert("success");
                }
            });
```

currently I am getting the following error:

Method: Post 
Status: Cancelled

in the network:

```
  Request Headers: CAUTION: provisional headers are shown
            Accept:*/*
            Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            Origin:http://localhost:5
            Referer:http://localhost:5/home.html
            User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
            Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded.

            Form Data:
            name:Rick Smith
            email:Rick@Smith.com
            list:hashedstring
```

Comment: Probably the same-origin problem.

Comment: @Barmar Would you mind elaborating? it is called on an <a></a> link. But the function returns false.

Comment: No one has any ideas?

Comment: You need to return `false` or call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default action of following the link. Following the link reloads the page and cancels any AJAX calls in progress.